# Slow fetch in react native

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch, expo

I don't know if it is a bug or something wrong with my code. But the first fetch takes to long to respond.
Although this problem is only on the app. When I run it on the web, it works like a charm and load within 2 to 3 seconds. While on the app it takes more than a minute.

```
fetch(url)
.then((response)=>response.json() )
.then((responseJson)=>{
  setDATA(responseJson);
  setLoading(false);
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

I also used Axios but having the same problem

```
axios.get(url)
.then(res => {
  setDATA(res.data);
  setLoading(false)
  console.log(DATA);
})
```

If you think this can be a large data problem. the SQL db has only 2 field to fetch from.
And It is same when i try to login user. Same slow fetch and slow response

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: email,
    password: password
  }),
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    setLoading(false);
    // If server response message same as Data Matched
    if (responseJson === 'Data Matched') {
      // save user to async
      // AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', true);

      //send user to main page
      navigation.navigate('flatlist');
    } else {
      alert(responseJson);
      console.log(responseJson)
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    setLoading(false);
    console.log(error);
  });
```

};

It also seems like a bug as I read [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28283)

Comment: Did you try it with minimal code? Try with a clean RN app.

Comment: cleaning doesn't help either, also when using different API like https://reactnative.dev/movies.json it works well and loads faster.

Comment: Did you solve this? What was it?